# How to return an int type representation for a list of objects

Tags: python

When outputting a list of objects how can you return an **int** type representation for the objects?

I've tried this:

```
class Passport(object):
    def __init__(self, my_id):
        self.id = my_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return int(self.id)



list_of_objects = [
Passport(19181),
Passport(29191),
Passport(39191)
]

if id in list_of_objects:
    print("true")
```

Where list_of_objects is a list of `Passport` instances. But this gives an error `__repr__ returned non-string (type int)`.

I could solve this problem using a string for both, but I'm wondering if type int is possible?

Comment: `__repr__()` needs to return a string, what is wrong with `return str(self.id)` ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) is *required* to return a **string** representation of the object. Returning a different type is not a valid implementation of `__repr__`.

If you want a way to return some number, then add a custom method that does that.

Btw., note that implementing `__repr__` is not a way to make `id in list_of_objects` work. For that to work, you should implement `__hash__` and `__eq__`. But at that point, you should really think about if you want `5 == Passport(5)` to be true; probably not. So you should change the way your check works by explicitely looking at the `id` property instead.

Instead of `if id in list_of_objects`, you could do the following:

```
if any(lambda x: x.id == id, list_of_objects):
    print('true')
```

Comment: Yes I could use something like ``__hash__`` but I want the actual list representation to be a set of numbers i.e. ``if id in list_of_objects.__hash__:``

Comment: Does that mean I would need to create another loop ? i.e. remove ``__repr__`` then loop again.

Comment: return it as string, and cast it later?

Comment: @Busturdust yes I know I can do that, but was wondering if there was another solution.

Comment: just make a get_id() method? `def get_id(): return self.id`

Comment: @Falcon1 you can just add special method that should return all existing ids. Something like that:
    
        ...
        @classmethod
        def get_ids(cls):
            return cls.ids
        ...
    
And, of course, don't forget to add id in a storage on `__init__`

Then you should use something like `if id in Passport.get_ids(): ...`

Comment: @poke I've tried setting a new method ``__hash__(self)`` but I get the error ``argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`` when doing ``if id in list_of_objects.__hash__:``

Comment: @Falcon1 By doing `list_of_objects.__hash__` you access the member on the list object, not your Passwort type. Also, that only returns a function, but not the hash values. Check my edit on how to perform this check.

Answer (score 1):

You could check a parallel list of the object ids instead.

```
if any(id == pp.id for pp in list_of_objects):
    print("true")
```

Answer (score 1):

`__repr__` must return a `str` as you have seen.

The proper way to do what you are asking is:

```
list_of_object_ids = [p.id for p in (Passport(19181), Passport(29191), Passport(39191))]
if id in list_of_objects:
    print("true")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Passport(object):
    def __init__(self, my_id):
        # It is recommended to call int here also in order to prevent
        # construction of invalid objects.
        self.id = int(my_id)

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.id)

list_of_objects = [
Passport(19181),
Passport(29191),
Passport(39191)
]

list_of_ints = [int(passport) for passport in list_of_objects]

if id in list_of_ints:
    print("true")
```